# Передать на сервер файлы Vuejs + Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.7

как передать на сервер файлы и обработать их?

```
<input type="file" @change="uploadImages(item,index)" name="galleryIndex" multiple accept="image/*"/>
```

и метод

```
uploadImages(item,index){
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('files', event.target.files);
            formData.append('index', index);

            const config = { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            axios.post('/upload/article/images',formData,config)
                .then((response) => {
                    alert(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {});
```

на сервере принимаю вот так

```
array:2 [
  "files" => "[object FileList]"
  "index" => "0"
]
```

и обрабатываю

```
$files = $request->file('files');
        foreach ($files as $item) {
            print_r($item);
        }
```

то выдает

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

in ArticleController.php line 12
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()', '/home/e/extremje/gymnastics/gimnastic/app/Http/Controllers/Uploads/ArticleController.php', 12, array('request' => object(Request), 'files' => null))
in ArticleController.php line 12Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

in ArticleController.php line 12
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()', '/home/e/extremje/gymnastics/gimnastic/app/Http/Controllers/Uploads/ArticleController.php', 12, array('request' => object(Request), 'files' => null))
in ArticleController.php line 12
```

Comment: проблема-то в чем?

Comment: не могу обработать файлы в контроллере выдает ошибку, обновил вопрос